# Confused with the use of __init__

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api

I created a class that it's created from the YouTube API. It looks like  this:

```
class YouTube:

  def __init__(self,name,version,developerKey):
        self.service=build(name, version, developerKey)

  def get_video_info(self,vid_id):
    vid_request = self.service.videos().list(
    part = 'snippet,statistics',
    id = vid_id,
    fields = 'items(kind,id,statistics)')

    vid_response = vid_request.execute()
    return vid_response

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    name = 'youtube'
    version = 'v3'
    api_token='xxxx'
    query=YouTube(name,version,api_token)

    vid_id='YYYYY_VID_ID'
    response = query.get_video_info(vid_id)

    pprint(response)
```

and it works fine, but then I tried the following on the **init** method:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'youtube'
    self.version = 'v3'
    self.developerKey = 'xxxxxxx'
    self.service = build(self.name, self.version,self.developerKey)


if __name__ == "__main__":    
     query = YouTube()
     response = query.get_video_info(vid_id)

     pprint(response)
```

I get the following error:

```
def get_video_info(self,vid_id):
    vid_request = self.service.videos().list(
    part = 'snippet,statistics',
    id=vid_id,
    fields= 'items(kind,id,statistics)')

    Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'request'

    vid_response = vid_request.execute()
```

I searched online and I see that this Exception occurs in a variety of situation, and I feel lost? Could someone point me in which direction I should search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build), this is how the `build` function is defined:

> `build(serviceName, version, http=None, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI, developerKey=None, model=None, requestBuilder=HttpRequest, credentials=None, cache_discovery=True, cache=None, client_options=None, adc_cert_path=None, adc_key_path=None, num_retries=1)`
>
> Construct a Resource for interacting with an API.

Therefore, you should pass the developer key as a keyword argument in your second snippet:

```json
self.service = build(
    self.name,
    self.version, 
    developerKey = self.developerKey
)
```